# Can not install ext-msgpack extension on mac os

Tags: php, macos, php-extension, php-7.1

I am unable to install msgpack php extension, which is required for my project.
My environment is php 7.1,  mac OS. The error is shown below:

```
Problem 1
- The requested PHP extension ext-msgpack * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's msgpack extension.
```

I tried installing with with brew, but still can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [brew](https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install php
```

And then

```
$ pecl install msgpack
```

This is the output of `php -m`:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
msgpack
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
phpdbg_webhelper
posix
pspell
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

As for now `brew` will install version `7.2`:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul 19 2018 12:15:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.8, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```